# How can I get the next and previous buttons working on my javascript code

Tags: javascript

I'm a new programmer learning and working on an image gallery with a full-screen popup using vanilla javascript and the console keep saying: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined at nextPic (app.js:35) at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (Imagegallery.html:18).
The HTML code. I have the script running at the end. I am wondering if I need to remove the last popup event listener?? So the user can just keep clicking through using the next and previous buttons. Then, I would like for it once the user gets to the end of the gallery it automatically returns back or could press and X put to exit. I hope this helps to get my problem figured out.

````
const popup = document.getElementById('popup');     //reference to popup
const selectedImage = document.getElementById('selectedImage'); //reference to selected image
const imageIndexes = [1,2,3]; //array of images
const selectedIndex = null;
var currPic = 0;
var pics= '';

//to show image gallery
imageIndexes.forEach((i)=>{
    const image = document.createElement('img'); //reference to image
    image.src=`images/logo${i}.PNG`; //updated the source with number dynamically
    image.classList.add('galleryImg'); // adding a css class
   
    image.addEventListener('click',() =>{
        //popup stuff
        popup.style.transform =`translateY(0)`; //image slide down when clicked
        selectedImage.src=`images/logo${i}.PNG`;
    })
    gallery.appendChild(image);
});

function nextPic(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (currPic < imageIndexes.length -1){
    currPic++;
    document.getElementById('prev').style.display = 'block';

    }
    else {
      document.getElementById('next').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('prev').style.display = 'block';
     }
  
    document.popup.src = imageIndexes[currPic];
}

function prevPic(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if (currPic > 0){
        currPic--;
      document.getElementById('next').style.display = 'block';  
    }
    
    else {
        document.getElementById('prev').style.display = 'none'; 
    }
    
document.popup.src = imageIndexes[currPic];
    
     
}

popup.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    popup.style.transform =`translateY(-100%)`; //image slides back up 
    popup.src ='';
});```




    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="image.css"> 
   
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
        <div id="gallery"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="popup">
        <img src="" alt="" id="selectedImage">
        <a href="#" onclick="prevPic(event); " id="prev">Prev</a>    <a href="#" onclick="nextPic(event);" id="next">Next</a>  
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
````

Comment: is it `image.src` `selectedImage.src` or `document.popup.src` or `popup.src` that's causing the error - please clarify

Comment: The error seem to be in `document.popup.src = imageIndexes[currPic];` ; `document.popup` is not assigned. Try `document.getElementById('popup').src = imageIndexes[currPic];` but there seem to be more problems than this; for example, `gallery.appendChild(image);` - `gallery` seem to be missing. html file would be also helpful.

Comment: When is the script being run? If it's in the head, likely the element doesn't exist when `popup = document.getElementById('popup');` is executed so `popup === null`.

Comment: @Bravo TBH I cant say. The console is only saying Cannot set property 'src' of undefined at nextPic (app.js:35) at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (Imagegallery.html:18).

Comment: @Max Gram, The console error disappears but instead of the picture going to the next picture or previous picture when clicking the next or previous button, the part of the code where the pop-up reverses back up so I could click a different picture.  I added the HTML

Comment: @RobG the script is being ran at the end on the HTML document

Comment: Which browser are you using? If the developer console doesn't somehow indicate which line of code is throwing the error, use a better browser

Comment: @Bravo i am using chrome

Comment: use a browser that shows where the error is thrown then